# Django not rendering html tags properly

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have an error message in `forms.py` to pass it to a template, but the template is rendering as a string not a html tag.

In `forms.py`

```
    message = ("The email address is already taken. Please <a href='#'> log in. </a>"

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        try:
            User.objects.get_by_natural_key(email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
              return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(message)
```

In a template

```
    <span class="error">{{form.email.errors|safe}}</span>
```

But this is rendering as 'The email address is already taken. Please `<a href='#'>`log in.`</a>`' not '
The email address is already taken. Please log in.'

I tried the autoescape tag, `{% autoescape off%}{{form.email.errors|safe}}{% endautoescape%}`, but this doesn't work either.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to:

```
raise forms.ValidationError(mark_safe(message))
```

See the [mark_safe documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) for more information

> For building up fragments of HTML, you should normally be using django.utils.html.format_html() instead